# What is the proper format for a color scheme config file for JetBrains PyCharm 2017.3.5 Community Edition?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, color-scheme, intellij-15

What is the proper format for a color scheme config file for Jet Brains PyCharm 2017.3.5 Community Edition?

I tried the following, but it caused an error `hot_fudge_sunday_color_scheme.icls`:

```
definition-foreground = #D92B10
error-foreground = #FF0000
string-background = #2B0F01
keyword-foreground = #4AD231
normal-foreground = #208008
comment-background = #2B0F01
hit-foreground = #208008
builtin-background = #2B0F01
stdout-foreground = #D92B10
cursor-foreground = #208008
break-background = #2B0F01
comment-foreground = #208008
hilite-background = #2F393C
hilite-foreground = #208008
definition-background = #2B0F01
stderr-background = #2B0F01
hit-background = #000000
console-foreground = #208008
normal-background = #2B0F01
builtin-foreground = #208008
stdout-background = #2B0F01
console-background = #2B0F01
stderr-foreground = #FB0000
keyword-background = #2B0F01
string-foreground = #BCBB80
break-foreground = #208008
error-background = #2B0F01
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an XML file like the following:

```
<scheme name="MyScheme" version="142" parent_scheme="Darcula">
  <metaInfo>
    <property name="created">2018-05-02T17:56:51</property>
    <property name="ide">PyCharmCore</property>
    <property name="ideVersion">2018.1.1.0.0</property>
    <property name="modified">2018-05-02T17:58:47</property>
    <property name="originalScheme">Monokai</property>
  </metaInfo>
  <colors>
    <option name="CARET_COLOR" value="f8f8f0" />
    <option name="CARET_ROW_COLOR" value="3e3d32" />
    <option name="CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_KEY" value="272822" />
    <option name="GUTTER_BACKGROUND" value="272822" />
    <option name="INDENT_GUIDE" value="3b3a32" />
    <option name="LINE_NUMBERS_COLOR" value="f8f8f2" />
    <option name="SELECTED_INDENT_GUIDE" value="3b3a32" />
    <option name="SELECTION_BACKGROUND" value="49483e" />
    <option name="WHITESPACES" value="3b3a32" />
  </colors>
  <attributes>
    <option name="BAD_CHARACTER">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="f8f8f0" />
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="f92672" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="BREAKPOINT_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="743d3d" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="BUILDOUT.KEY">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="f92672" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="BUILDOUT.KEY_VALUE_SEPARATOR">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="f92672" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="BUILDOUT.LINE_COMMENT">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="75715e" />
      </value>
    </option>

    ...
    <option name="YAML_TEXT">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="f8f8f2" />
      </value>
    </option>
  </attributes>
</scheme>
```

You can inspect existing `.icls` files in `<PyCharm config dir>/colors` folder to see what they look like